# How to manipulate data on the rendered texture

Tags: opengl

I would like to manipulate the rendered pixel data in OpenGL. For example, in the figure below, the red rectangle is my grey-value image, I load it to a texture and then render to fill the full screen (black rectangle), using following code:

```cpp
void draw_quad(GLuint texture)
{
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(glfwGetCurrentContext(), &width, &height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(-0.25f, -0.25f);
    glVertex2f(0.f, 0.f);

    glTexCoord2f(1.25f, -0.25f);
    glVertex2f(1.f, 0.f);

    glTexCoord2f(1.25f, 1.25f);
    glVertex2f(1.f, 1.f);

    glTexCoord2f(-0.25f, 1.25f);
    glVertex2f(0.f, 1.f);

    glEnd();
}
```

[image: Description]

How may I, sequentially:

1. Read the rendered screen pixels out (i.e. the full screen image);
2. and then manipulate on the full-screen pixels. I prefer manipulating on device, but copy back and then manipulate on CPU is also acceptable;
3. Render the manipulated new full-screen pixels back, and show it on screen.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What kind of manipulation are we talking about? In many cases, you can render the source image to a texture and use this as the source texture for another render pass where you apply your modifications in the fragment shader.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks for the reply. By manipulation I mean pixel-wise substration of another full-screen image, and then wrap the substrated result (may contain negative values) into the range of [0 255]. I am new to OpenGL and shader. I had a look into basic shader language and your suggestion seems good. Thank you!

Comment: There can be many ways to solve this. Check up on Multi-render-target rendering on how to render to off-screen textures.

Comment: @StarShine Thanks for your proposal. I have solved it now, by using two textures and a fragment shader that blends them using different texture coordinates.